# How can I get "Save Image" as an option in the Share Sheet?

Tags: uiactivityviewcontroller, ios-sharesheet, swiftui-sharelink, sharelink

I'm trying to present a share sheet with an image. I'd expect the "Save Image" option to be there but it's not. Is there some trick to getting this working?

Answer (score 2):

The poorly documented solution (and wildly unnecessary from a privacy standpoint since it requires no user approval?) is to add `NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription` to your `info.plist`. Then the option will magically appear. ✌️